# How to integrate fetched JSON data with Room Persistence library

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android Application (Android Studio - Java) which includes a sign in and registration process. I took care of the sign in and registration processes by implementing a connection between PHP files and a MySQL database through http. In short, I just created an AsyncTask class in java --called from another class-- and used it to post data to a PHP file, from there I just used the appropriate SQL commands. This part works fine.

This first part with the login and registration is important because every user will see a slightly different layout once they login. The layout is a RecyclerView composed of detailed CardView elements. Each CardView has a few TextViews with some details. The details are held by an Object i created in a separate class. To fill in the CardView elements a fetched some JSON data using a separate PHP file (and one more http connection). Parsing the data from JSON into Strings and ints was a straightforward endeavor, as was adding them to the list of custom objects. There is some code below showing how I fetched the data and added it to the Object list.

This is the complete AsyncTask class:

```
public class ScheduleWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
ScheduleWorker (Context ctx) { context = ctx; }

@Override
protected  void onPreExecute() { super.onPreExecute(); }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute (String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        loadJSON(s);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    final String fetch_url = "http://192.168.1.70/newfetcher.php";

    try {
        String ussr_name = params[0];
        URL url = new URL(fetch_url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(ussr_name, "UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String json;

        while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(json + "\n");
        }

        return sb.toString().trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private void loadJSON(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    Course course;
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
    int len = jsonArray.length();

    String[] titles = new String[len];
    String[] types = new String[len];
    String[] teachers = new String[len];
    int[] pics = new int[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        titles[i] = obj.getString("title");
        types[i] = obj.getString("type");
        teachers[i] = obj.getString("teacher");
        pics[i] = obj.getInt("pic");
        course = new Course(titles[i], types[i], teachers[i], pics[i]);
        courses.add(course);
    }
}
}
```

Now, where I encountered problems is when I tried saving the List of Objects (and their details) to a Room Persistent Database. I based my code for the Room Database off an example from [Google Developer CodeLabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view). I adapted the code for my particular needs but I kept the underlying class structure. The structure includes: an Entity, a DAO, a RoomDatabase, a Repository, a ViewModel, a ViewHolder, an Adapter for the RecyclerView, and a class to populate the database. Everything seems fine except for the part where I populate the database. The example populates the database by using a callback and an AsyncTask within the RoomDatabase class.

Here is populating AsyncTask:

```
private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        // If you want to keep the data through app restarts,
        // comment out the following line.
        new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();
    }
};

/**
 * Populate the database in the background.
 * If you want to start with more words, just add them.
 */
private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final WordDao mDao;

    PopulateDbAsync(WordRoomDatabase db) {
        mDao = db.wordDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // Start the app with a clean database every time.
        // Not needed if you only populate on creation.

        Word word = new Word("Hello");
        mDao.insert(word);
        word = new Word("World");
        mDao.insert(word);
        return null;
    }
}
```

My question is how do I populate the database with the detail arrays and/or the Object list? The example executes the callback every time a adding activity is called. I just want to populate the database when the user registers.

Comment: Are you trying to save courses `List<Course> courses` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to save courses to a room persistent database, so that the user doesn't have to load all their data every time they log in. The Async Task for fetching the data is called in the onPostExecute method of the registration Async Task, so I just want to the save the data once when the user register